# Нужно найти подстроку (subs) в строке (string) используя цикл for

Tags: javascript

Есть задача:

Даны два аргумента subs и string. Функция должна вернуть длину минимальной подстроки, где есть все буквы subs в том же порядке. Или ноль, если присутствуют не все символы. (использовать в основе цикл for)

Допустим subs = 'abc', string = 'afmdnfabbabicd'.

С данными аргументами минимальная подстрока окажется 'abic', т.е. функция должна вернуть 4.

Подскажите оптимальный способ решения через цикл (циклы) for.

```
const subs = 'abc';
const string = 'afmdnfabbabicd';

let check = (subs, string) => {

// решение

};

console.log(check(subs, string));
```

P.S.
Мой вариант, который находит лишь первое вхождение. Другого пока не придумал.

```
let check = (subs, string) => {
  let x = 0
  let y = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    if (subs[x] === string[i]) {
      x += 1
      y = i + 1
    }
  }
  return ((x === subs.length) ? (y - string.indexOf(subs[0])) : 0)
};
```

```js
let check = (subs, string) => {
  let x = 0
  let y = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
    if (subs[x] === string[i]) {
      x += 1
      y = i + 1
    }
  }
  return ((x === subs.length) ? (y - string.indexOf(subs[0])) : 0)
};

console.log(check('abc', 'afmdnfabbabicd'));
```

Comment: самый-самый оптимальный? А у Вас есть хоть какой-нибудь?

Comment: @Igor есть несколько. Не публикую, чтобы не сбивать с толку, так как у меня нет оптимального. Вас задело слово "самый". Удалю, чтобы не нервировать вас.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, меня задело выражение "самый оптимальный". Оно - в русском языке, который я помню, - означает "самый самый лучший". Но, как выясняется, Вы хотели сказать "правильный".

Comment: Самый оптимальный - использовать префикс-функцию. Впрочем не факт. Она будет только вхождение префикса `subs` считать. За произведение длин пойдёт решение? Блин.. Вообще неправильно условие понял. Вроде так ещё проще. Завтра подумаю, если не забуду. Если все символы в искомой строке разные, то вроде легко решается за линейное время. А вот если все одинаковые, то скатывается к произведению длин. Хотя...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь моему наставнику Игорю, который помог мне выполнить задачу следующим образом:

```js
const subs = 'abc';
const string = 'afmdnfabbabicd';

let check = (subs, string) => {

  let x = []
  let x1 = []

  for (let k = 0; k < string.length; k += 1) {
    if (subs[0] === string[k]) {
      x[k] = 0
    }

    const xKeys = [...Object.keys(x)];

    for (let i = 0; i < xKeys.length; i += 1) {
      if (!(x[xKeys[i]] >= subs.length)) {

        if (subs[x[xKeys[i]]] === string[k]) {
          x[xKeys[i]] += 1
        }
        if (x[xKeys[i]] === subs.length) {
          x1.push((k - xKeys[i]) + 1)
        }

      }
    }
  }

  return x1.length === 0 ? 0 : Math.min(...x1)
}

console.log(check(subs, string));
```

Comment: Ну вроде работает, только Infinity вместо 0.

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, да, щас подправлю. Спасибо!

Comment: Мне кажется, можно эффективнее. Сейчас подумаю...

Comment: @Qwertiy Если можно, буду только рад увидеть, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - искать в лоб. Получается алгоритм за квадрат длины строки, в которой делается поиск:

```js
function solve(t, s) {
  var res = s.length + 1

  for (var q=0; q<s.length; ++q) {
    if (s[q] === t[0]) {
      for (var w=0, e=q, lim=q+res; e<lim; ++e) {
        if (s[e] === t[w]) {
          if (++w === t.length) {
            res = e - q + 1
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return res>s.length ? 0 : res
}

console.log(solve("abc", "afmdnfabbabicd"))                          // 4
console.log(solve("a", "aaaaaaa"))                                   // 1
console.log(solve("aaaa", "aaaaaaa"))                                // 4
console.log(solve("aaaa", "aaabaaaa"))                               // 4
console.log(solve("aaaa", "aaababaaa"))                              // 5
console.log(solve("aaaa", "aacababaaa"))                             // 5
console.log(solve("abacaba", "abavbsvdgsjdvagvxgashdfsbabadsafaf"))  // 0
console.log(solve("abacaba", "abavbsvdgsjdvagvxcgashdfsbabadsafaf")) // 25
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

s.length ? 0 : res

Comment: Пока не получилось отпимизировать нормально...

Comment: Спасибо, да, тоже хороший вариант по-моему.

Comment: @DENTRE, вроде твой лучше, зато этот просто пишется. У меня квадрат длины большой строки, а у тебя вроде произведение длин. Мне кажется, его можно свести в квадрату меньшей строки, либо вообще к линейному от большой, но я что-то пока не придумал. Идея, которая была, получается какая-то запутанная и всё равно квадрат большей.

Comment: Нравятся оба. Классно то, что по сути разный подход показали к решению задачи. Если кому-то понадобится решение, сможет для себя выбрать оптимальное.

Answer (score 1):

Так как ответов пока ни у кого нет, то я решил вот таким способом (здесь минимум итераций по сравнению с другими решениями). Расстраивает, что вы даже не попробовали решить эту задачу.

```js
const subs = 'abc';
const string = 'afmdnfabbabicd';

let check = (subs, string) => {
  let reg = subs[0];
  for(let i = 1; i < subs.length; i++) {
    reg += '\\w*' + subs[i]
  }
  let regexp = new RegExp(`${reg}`, 'gi');

  if(string.match(regexp) === null) return 0;

  let position = string.indexOf(subs[0]);
  let result = string.length;
  
  while(true) {
    let found = string.slice(position).match(regexp);

    if (found === null) return result;
  
    if(found[0].length < result) result = found[0].length;

    position = string.indexOf(subs[0], position+1);
    if(position < 0 )  return result;
  }
};

console.log(check(subs, string));
```

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь. Пробовал. Мое решение, к сожалению, работает не корректно. Находит первое вхождение.
Ещё есть через три цикла for, не моё, но это не оптимально совсем. n + 2
Ещё работаю над вариантом с массивом, как что-то нащупаю, опубликую.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const subs = 'abc';
const string = 'afmbdnfacbbabicd';

let check = (subs, string) => {
  var s = "";
  var is = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (subs.indexOf(string[i]) != -1) {
      s = s + string[i];
      is.push(i);
    }
  }
  //console.log(s, JSON.stringify(is));
  var r = findLength(0);
  for (i = 1; r && i < string.length; i++) {
    var r1 = findLength(i);
    //console.log(i,r1);
    if (r1 != null)
      r = Math.min(r, r1);
  }
  return r;
  
  function findLength(start) {
    var r = null;
    var idx = start - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
      var idx = s.indexOf(subs[i], idx + 1);
      if (idx == -1)
        return null;
      if (i == 0) {
        r = is[idx]; //console.log(is[idx]);
      } else if (i == subs.length - 1) {
        r = is[idx] - r + 1; //console.log(is[idx]);
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
};

console.log(check(subs, string));
```

Comment: Для других значений выдает с ошибкой. Плюс количество итераций для примера приведенного в задаче у вас около 60. Хотя и подстрока, и сама строка маленькие.